# Two definitions of p-value

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

According to Casella-Berger (2002) the definition of p-value (def. 8.3.26, §8.3.4, p. 397) is:

> A p-value $p(X)$ is a test statistic satisfying $0 \le p(x) \le 1$ for
> every sample point $x$. Small values of $p(X)$ give evidence that
> $H_1$ is true. A p-value is valid if, for every $\theta \in \Theta_0$
> and every $0 \le \alpha \le 1$, $P_{\theta}(p(X) \le \alpha) \le
>  \alpha$.

However, other books such as Rohatgi (2001) define it as:

> The probability of observing under $H_0$ a sample outcome at least as
> extreme as the one observed is called the P-value. The smaller the
> P-value, the more extreme the outcome and the stronger the evidence
> against $H_0$.

I feel this definition is similar in spirit to the one by Schervish (2012):

> p-value. In general, the p-value is the smallest level $\alpha_0$ such
> that we would reject the null-hypothesis at level $\alpha_0$ with the
> observed data.

How are these definitions equivalent?

Comment: Just as a suggestion... in case you don't get any answers here, I'd recommend [Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The definition 0f Casella-Berger is precise,abstract, and works in both frequentist and Bayesian frameworks. The other 2 are not so much formal definitions as procedural descriptions. I would add to both of them the idea that 'extreme' means _in the direction_ (or directions) of the alternative:('extremely small' if the alternative is left-sided, 'extremely large if right-sided. 'extremely far from null value' if two-sided. The C-B definition, hints at the important property that (for continuous test statistics) a P-value is a random variable uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ if $H_0$ is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between these definitions is that, while the first one presents a property that a p-value must satisfy, the latter ones define the p-value as a function of a collection of hypothesis tests. It is possible to show that these definitions are related, as I discuss below.

Note that the latter two definitions refer to varying levels of significance. In order to make these definitions operational, you must consider a collection of hypothesis tests. Formally, an hypothesis test, $\phi: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is a function from the sample space that assumes the value $1$ if $H_0$ is rejected and the value $0$, otherwise. Let $(\phi_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in (0,1)}$ be a collection of hypothesis tests such that $\phi_{\alpha}$ has size $\alpha$ and that satisfy monotonicity, that is, if $\alpha_1 \leq \alpha_2$, then for every $x$, $\phi_{\alpha_1}(x) \leq \phi_{\alpha_2}(x)$. The latter two definitions say that the p-value is a function $p: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow (0,1)$ such that $p(x)=\inf \{\alpha: \phi_{\alpha}(x)=1\}$. Observe that, for every $\theta \in H_0$,

\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{P}_\theta(p(X) \leq \alpha^*)
 &= \mathbb{P}_\theta(\inf \{\alpha: \phi_{\alpha}(X)=1\} \leq \alpha^*) \\
 &= \mathbb{P}_\theta(\phi_{\alpha^*}(X)=1)
 & \text{monotonicity} \\ 
 &\leq \alpha^* 
 & \phi_{\alpha^*} \text{ has size } \alpha^*
\end{align*}

This shows that the p-value as in Rohatgi and Schervish satisfies the property presented in Casella.

Next, consider that $p: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow (0,1)$ is a function such that, for every $\theta \in H_0$, $P_{\theta}(p(X) \leq \alpha^*) \leq \alpha^*$. In this case, you can define a collection of hypothesis tests such that $\phi_{\alpha}(x)=\mathbb{I}(p(x) \leq \alpha)$. It follows from the initial definition that each $\phi_{\alpha}$ has size $\alpha$. Also, it follows from construction that, if $\alpha_1 \leq \alpha_2$, then for every $x$, $\phi_{\alpha_1}(x) \leq \phi_{\alpha_2}(x)$. Finally, note that
$p(x) = \inf\{\alpha: \phi_{\alpha}(x)=1\}$. That is, you can construct a collection of hypothesis tests based on Casella's definition. If you apply Rohatgi's or Schervishe's definition to this class, then you obtain $p(x)$.

Comment: This is nice! It shows how to derive a p-value from such a class of monotone hypothesis tests and vice versa. But it's a stretch to say that Rohatgi's and Schervish's "definitions" are the p-value that you defined via the tests $\phi_\alpha$, $\alpha \in (0,1)$. That requires a good deal of interpretation. I'd say that Rohatgi and Schervish give intuitive expanations of p-values, but don't rigorously define them. (At least not in the quotes provided.)